# How start a new browser with selenium？

Tags: python, firefox, browser, selenium

I should start Firefox Using this code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

But, I want to use myself browser not firefox\chrome\opera\ie which we develop myself, How should I start it with selenium, and use Python?

Comment: I may be missing something here, but all you need to do is create a class that extends webDriver, and for each of the methods, it does the appropriate action on your own browser

Comment: Are you saying you developed your own browser and want to launch it using Selenium?

Comment: I want to write API which it can operate myself browser, because I do automatic test on myself browser platform. I need some resources(such as github code/bolgs/documents etc).

Comment: You will have to explain a little more. What is "myself browser"?

Comment: I mean that Selenium(webdriver) does not have an existing API for my browser, but it have API which is webdriver.Firefox() for FireFox browser. Now I want selenium(webdriver) to support this new browser, this should be required to write own API(similars to webdriver.Firefox()).